# How pass data to Vue.js app from external source?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a small Vue app that will be placed inside a page - done with Drupal 8. 
I can't find if - and eventually how - pass data from the outside to this Vue app.

I know I could set a rest service to call to get that info, but that would be an overkill, as I need to pass only a couple of numbers - an id or two.

So I'm looking for a way to save this info from the "outside" and then access from inside the Vue app. 
A possible solution I'm thinking of is to use the window object:

E.g. from "outside" vue

```js
window.MyProperty = {}; 
MyProperty.value = 1;
```

and then in Vue

```
Vue.prototype.MyProperty = window.MyProperty;
```

(I haven't tested that yet, I hope it works).

But I'd like to know if there are better and proper "vue" ways to obtain this.

Comment: which Vue version are you using?

Comment: "_then access from inside the Vue_" you mean you would like to access the `value` like a regular data option?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim version 2.6.11

Comment: @palaѕн yes, I'd like to access the `value` set up from external source like a regular data  inside Vue - however I won't need to change it, nor update it in the external html page\js files. In other words, I need of that number to execute some logic inside Vue.